# How to update attendee list to host in icalender

Tags: outlook, icalendar

i'm having issues in sending icalender update to host of the meeting. here i have paste both two of my calender.ics files.

First invitation, with publish method is working and adding to the calender without any issues. But when i send the second email as a update with new attendees(using REQUEST), its not updating with my first calender invitation in outlook.

---

### First Invitation

```
            BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
            VERSION:2.0
            CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
            METHOD:PUBLISH
            STATUS:Testbooking
            X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
            BEGIN:VEVENT
            CLASS:PUBLIC
            CREATED:20140916T060318Z
            DESCRIPTION:
            DTEND:20140916T090037Z
            DTSTAMP:20140916T060320Z
            DTSTART:20140916T083037Z
            LAST-MODIFIED:20140916T060320Z
            LOCATION:Chai Chee - Oasis.Oasis.4th Floor.Celebes
            ORGANIZER;CN=Marlen Brayan:mailto:pasan@ecyber.com
            PRIORITY:5
            SEQUENCE:1
            SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Testbooking
            TRANSP:OPAQUE
            UID:events.ivivaworks.com_FB_Booking_48
            X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
                <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n
                <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version rmj.rmm.rup.rpr">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n
                </HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us">
                <FONT FACE="Calibri">
                </FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
            X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
            BEGIN:VALARM
            TRIGGER:-PT15M
            ACTION:DISPLAY
            DESCRIPTION:Reminder
            END:VALARM
            END:VEVENT
            END:VCALENDAR
```

---

### Second Invitation

```
            BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
            VERSION:2.0
            CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
            METHOD:REQUEST
            STATUS:Testbooking
            X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
            BEGIN:VEVENT
            ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="Frederic Reboulleau";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:frederic.reboulleau@orange.com
            ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="pasan fernando";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:i.pasan@yahoo.com
            CLASS:PUBLIC
            CREATED:20140916T060318Z
            DESCRIPTION:
            DTEND:20140916T090037Z
            DTSTAMP:20140916T061357Z
            DTSTART:20140916T083037Z
            LAST-MODIFIED:20140916T061357Z
            LOCATION:Chai Chee - Oasis.Oasis.4th Floor.Celebes
            ORGANIZER;CN=Marlen Brayan:mailto:pasan@ecyber.com
            PRIORITY:5
            SEQUENCE:4
            SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Testbooking
            TRANSP:OPAQUE
            UID:events.ivivaworks.com_FB_Booking_48
            X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
                <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n
                <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version rmj.rmm.rup.rpr">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n
                </HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us">
                <FONT FACE="Calibri">
                </FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
            X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
            X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
            BEGIN:VALARM
            TRIGGER:-PT15M
            ACTION:DISPLAY
            DESCRIPTION:Reminder
            END:VALARM
            END:VEVENT
```

### END:VCALENDAR

![enter image description here][1]

This is how second invitation shows in outlook. it shows as no response required. but its not updating with first email too. am i doing anything wrong in formatting of ics file?

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious problem. Your file passes the online validator. Your UIDs are the same. Your sequence number advances, though it should be 0 in the first invitation.

In general, Outlook is very picky, and the only approach that works I find is to copy exactly a working example. Use Gmail to generate an invitation, then modify the event and resend from Gmail. Note exactly how the second invitation is processed by Outlook. Do you need to preview the invitation to provoke the calendar update? Use Gmail "show original" to inspect and copy exactly the structure of the Icalendar, including the order of fields.